Layout Issues When Scrolling with Added Content in HTML/CSS
I'm having some HTML/CSS trouble on my I guess it would be a quick fix, but not for me right now.
I put the code in a JSFiddle to easily show the issue.
Problem Description
When I access my site from my phone, it appears very zoomed out.
I then added this code:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
This fix the zoom issue, but this hasn't resolved the layout issues.
When I add additional content to my site and scroll down, the layout doesn't behave as expected. It seams to break the design. The issue only occurs on mobile devices.
Cheers!

The issue is that your background not covering everything there is. To fix this, have the background not move when you scroll down the page. This may be done with this change:
#vanta {
    position: fixed;
}

Instead of your current code which is:
#vanta {
    position: absolute;
}

Hope this helps!
